# wpa_supplicant - detecting that my password is incorrect?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant, wpa2-psk

If I specify an incorrect password when connecting to a WiFi network is there anyway to detect that the reason I can't connect is the incorrect password (rather than one of the many other possible reasons that one might not be able to connect).

E.g. here I add a network but deliberately specify the wrong password. If I check the status I just see that it's `SCANNING`

```
# wpa_cli add_network
Selected interface 'wlan0'
1
# wpa_cli set_network 1 ssid \"MyPlace\"
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
# wpa_cli set_network 1 psk \"SuperSecret\"
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
# wpa_cli select_network 1
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
# wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'wlan0'
wpa_state=SCANNING
p2p_device_address=fe:c2:de:37:93:11
address=fc:c2:de:37:93:11
```

If I write a script to run `wpa_cli status` repeatedly after selecting the network I can see it goes through the phases:

```
SCANNING
ASSOCIATING
4WAY_HANDSHAKE
DISCONNECTED
SCANNING
```

So is there some way to discover that the association/handshake phase failed due to an incorrect password? E.g. does the disconnect event report some reason that's stored and which I can then query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at [`wpa_supplicant/events.c:2326`](http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/events.c?id=1acf38f1a5aa19169035de9b611fc76440729c0b#n2326) we see:

```
if (could_be_psk_mismatch(wpa_s, reason_code, locally_generated)) {
    wpa_msg(wpa_s, MSG_INFO, "WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - "
        "pre-shared key may be incorrect");
    if (wpas_p2p_4way_hs_failed(wpa_s) > 0)
        return; /* P2P group removed */
    wpas_auth_failed(wpa_s, "WRONG_KEY");
}
```

So when this logic is hit it logs `WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect`.

Then it carries on to [`wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.c:5136`](http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.c?id=1acf38f1a5aa19169035de9b611fc76440729c0b#n5136) and we see:

```
wpa_msg(wpa_s, MSG_INFO, WPA_EVENT_TEMP_DISABLED
    "id=%d ssid=\"%s\" auth_failures=%u duration=%d reason=%s",
    ssid->id, wpa_ssid_txt(ssid->ssid, ssid->ssid_len),
    ssid->auth_failures, dur, reason);
```

So here `<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyPlace" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY` is logged.

So I can either ensure that `wpa_supplicant` is started such that it logs its output to a file and then `grep` for such messages.

Or I can run `wpa_cli` in interactive mode - when it's in this mode it will subscribe for and output any `wpa_supplicant` messages.

So the very hacky solution I came up with was to run `wpa_cli` in a script and fool it into thinking it's in interactive mode:

```
#!/bin/bash

function poke {
    while true
    do
        printf '\n'
        sleep 1
    done
}

function watch {
    (poke) | wpa_cli | while read line
    do
        case "$line" in
            *'4-Way Handshake failed'*)
                echo "incorrect key"
                return
            ;;
            *'CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED'*)
                echo "connected"
                return
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

wpa_cli disable_network 0 > /dev/null
wpa_cli enable_network 0 > /dev/null

watch
```

`wpa_cli` will only output any messages it has received after some user input has occurred, so the `poke` function provides this.

This script enables the 0<sup>th</sup> network and looks at what `wpa_supplicant` outputs while doing this.

Like I said this is pretty hacky but it works.

Comment: In https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768467/dhcpcd-times-out-at-waiting-for-carrier/768468 we see how confusing lack of simple "wrong password" messages can be.